# error while using math.pow in java code

Tags: java, math

i have a java code for finding out netsalary . I keep Getting "`bad operand type for binary operator ' / '`" error . The Line goes like this

```
netSalary = Double.parseDouble(principle2*rate2/12*Math.pow(rate2/12+1))/(Double.parseDouble(Math.pow(rate2/12+1)-1));
```

Could this be solved . Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read the javadoc of the methods you are using.

Comment: `Double.parseDouble` takes a `String` argument, looks for a real number, and returns a `double`.  You have no `String`s anywhere in this expression, so I don't know what you were trying to accomplish by calling this method.

Answer (score 2):

It should be commas you use, not slashes.

`Math.pow(rate2/12+1)` should syntactically be in the form of `Math.pow(x,y)` where both `x` and `y` are doubles. The first arg is the base, and second arg is the index you're raising it to. As the comment below mentioned, it's difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve, and you'll have to substitute x and y for the correct values - **make sure they're of type double** (you cannot use, for example, `12+1` as a parameter because it is an integer). If it is an integer, then type cast it using `(double)` in front of the value.

You also do not need to `parseDouble` everywhere since `Math.pow` will return double values anyways; it is redundant.

I agree with the comment above; please read the javadocs for any problems you're having with a method before posting here.

Comment: `Math.pow(rate2,12+1)` is certainly wrong.  However, I don't know just what's right.  It looks like for the formula for interest, except that the left argument of `Math.pow` is definitely not `rate2`, and I don't know why he's assigning it into a `salary` variable.  In any case, please edit your post and get rid of the "should be", because although you've used `Math.pow` right, the answer is definitely wrong.

Comment: You're right; changed it. I was simply stating how the method would be used syntactically.

Answer (score 0):

You mistake in using power function your power function should be like this

```
Math.pow((rate2/12+1),1)
```

Comment: Ummm... you really think it can be right to use `Math.pow` with a literal 1 as the right argument?  And the second version is also certainly wrong (see my other comment).

Comment: yes but i am suggesting him how to use the power funtion

Comment: @ajb yes? "If the second argument is 1.0, then the result is the same as the first argument."

Comment: @RishiDwivedi Better, I think, to show him using `x` and `y`, or even some unrelated example from physics, than to show him the correct syntax using an incorrect formula.

Comment: @djechlin Right, that's basic math.  Are you agreeing with me, or if not, what's your point?  My point is that nobody would ever write that, therefore it can't be the right answer (and is certainly not what the OP intended to compute).